# I Am Inside You, But Never Others, And I'm A Spy For Both Groups. What Am I?

Tags: riddle

I am inside you, but never others,

Everybody always uses me every second, more than once,

When you want to ask a question, I am something good to bring up,

If you change me even a little, I become an adult, and if you do it again, I become a kid,

I am a spy for both groups, but one group is called more often, despite having less members,

If I am lucky enough to be on a flag, I will be red and yellow, but in real life, filled with color, I am blue.

What Am I?

---

(The following is NOT part of the riddle:) Please explain your reasoning for each clue and conceal our answer/reasoning behind a spoiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is:

> The letter Y.

I am inside you, but never others

> The word "you" has a Y, but not the word "others"

Everybody always uses me every second, more than once

> The word "everybody" has 2 Y's.

When you want to ask a question, I am something good to bring up

> You often need to ask "why".

If you change me even a little, I become an adult, and if you do it again, I become a kid

> If you change the bottom of a 'y' to be straight, it becomes a capital Y (an adult).  If you move it back, it becomes a lowercase y (a kid).

I am a spy for both groups, but one group is called more often, despite having less members

> The letter Y is considered to be both a consonant and a vowel.  Vowels are used more often than consonants despite there being fewer of them.

If I am lucky enough to be on a flag, I will be red and yellow, but in real life, filled with color, I am blue

> The [flag of Vanuatu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Vanuatu) has a yellow Y with a red stripe.  I don't know why a Y would be blue in real life though, unless it is referring to "sky".

Comment: You're a good puzzle solver! Congratz!

Comment: @Xandawesome Could you explain the part about the flag and the the blue?  I just guessed on that part.

Comment: The signal flag for the letter "Y" is red and yellow stripes. Also the text "Y" converted to color (rgb) is blue. ;)

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be

> A heart?

**Explanation line by line:**

I am inside you, but never others,

> Your heart has to be inside you.

Everybody always uses me every second, more than once,

> Your heart beats more then 60 times a minute so you you use it more then once a second.

If you change me even a little, I become an adult, and if you do it again, I become a kid,

> Some people have to get a new heart, this can be from a younger person.

*No idea for the rest of the lines yet.*

Comment: 60 times a second!? wow dude, you should have that checked out ;)

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat Whoops, fixed that ^^

Comment: Good answer, but not what I was looking for. Upvoted. ;)